# How to be proficient and efficient with NetBeans?

Tags: java, templates, netbeans, ide

Dear people of stackoverflow,

I am learning to code Java and recently switched from programming in text editors and compiling in terminal windows to an actual IDE, NetBeans (I know, I'm a dinosaur. I inherited the habit from C++). The point is, I'm really lost.

I installed NetBeans because I saw some friends from school open the application and write about 50 lines of code in half the time it took me. I'm guessing they use some sort of templates or customized settings.

I would really appreciate it if you could shed some light in the subject, because I want to be as fast and efficient as possible when coding, especially when dealing with really long assignments.

Comment: https://usersguide.netbeans.org/shortcuts.pdf

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this is far too broad a question here.  There will be no shortcuts to diving in and assimilating the IDE.  If you've never used one there will be a period where it feels like it takes longer to do something, but with a little practice you will begin to appreciate the 10x productivity improvement you can get, especially when debugging.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'll definitely look up some stuff and probably scan through the manual a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something that can be quickly answered in this format.

The main advantages are:

- Intellisense/Code completion (start typing code, press ctrl-space)
- As-you-type error checking and reporting with automatic fixes in some places
- Code generation (source->generate code)
- Navigation (go to source, go to decleration, find references, etc).
- Integrated debugging
- Refactoring (renaming variables, methods and classes; introducing classes and methods; etc).

Try all of those things to get you started but there are many many more.

Answer (score 1):

There's not going to be any one silver bullet; this is the accumulation of many small efficiencies, including keyboard shortcuts, advanced features, templates, etc.

You should take a closer look at what your friends do, and each time you see them doing something you don't, ask them about it. Better yet, each time you come across a task that intuitively seems like there should be a better way to do it (e.g. typing a similar pattern over and over), google around and see if there *is* a better way. There likely is!

For a more rigorous approach, of course, you can read the NetBeans manual end-to-end in order to get a comprehensive understanding of its features. I've never done that for my IDE of choice, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Ok, you have an IDE (that's good!). With it you can make a lot of shortcuts for developing. Here some tips:**

---

- You can create a project using a template by going `File -> New Project -> <LANGUAGE> -> <TEMPLATE>`. This template will autogenerate a basic source for what you want.
- You can put breakpoints in any place only clicking in a line number.
- You can debug by going to `Debug -> Debug Project`
- You can auto-generate a double-clickable `.jar` by going to `Build -> Clean and Build`
- You can run a console program directly in the IDE, by using `Build -> Run Project`
- You can even install `plugins` for extending the IDE's functionality

---

***There're lots of things I'm not telling you, cause it's a long list. You can see [NetBeans Documentation](https://netbeans.org/kb/) for more info.***